# -[UITextField propertyAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes]?

Tags: xcode, uikit, code-completion

I made a subclass of `UITextField` and declared the following property in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isFakeHidden) BOOL fakeHidden;
```

When, I go into the `.m` file and type `- fa` it suggests `- (NSArray *)fakeHiddenAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes`

[image: Xcode code completion]

What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll need to clear the Xcode index, so it will rescan your sources, and rebuild it.

Close your Xcode project, open the organizer, go to "Projects", select your project and click "Clear derived data".

The re-open your project. Xcode will re-index it.